# Pandas: divide dataframe to some parts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe

```
ID   url
111   vk.com
111   facebook.com
111   twitter.com
111   avito.ru
111   apple.com
111   tiffany.com
111   pikabu.ru
111   stackoverflow.com
222   vk.com
222   facebook.com
222   vc.ru
222   twitter.com
```

I need to add new column `part`, where I should groupby dataframe with `ID` and next divide it to 4 parts.
Desire output

```
    ID   url   part
111   vk.com   1
111   facebook.com   1
111   twitter.com   2
111   avito.ru   2
111   apple.com   3
111   tiffany.com   3
111   pikabu.ru   4
111   stackoverflow.com   4
222   vk.com   1
222   facebook.com   2
222   vc.ru   3
222   twitter.com   4
```

I tried

```
df.groupby(['ID']).agg({'ID': np.sum / 4}).rename(columns={'ID': 'part'}).reset_index()
```

But I don't get desirable with it

Comment: Will all ID groups always be multiples of 4?

Comment: @pshep123 yes, I need to divide to 4 parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` with [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
df['part'] = df.groupby('ID')['ID']
               .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.repeat(np.arange(1, 5), (len(x.index) / 4))))
               .reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
     ID                url  part
0   111             vk.com     1
1   111       facebook.com     1
2   111        twitter.com     2
3   111           avito.ru     2
4   111          apple.com     3
5   111        tiffany.com     3
6   111          pikabu.ru     4
7   111  stackoverflow.com     4
8   222             vk.com     1
9   222       facebook.com     2
10  222              vc.ru     3
11  222        twitter.com     4
```

Another solution with custom function:

```
def f(x):
    #print (x)
    x['part'] = np.repeat(np.arange(1, 5), (len(x.index) / 4))
    return x

df = df.groupby('ID').apply(f)
print (df)
     ID                url  part
0   111             vk.com     1
1   111       facebook.com     1
2   111        twitter.com     2
3   111           avito.ru     2
4   111          apple.com     3
5   111        tiffany.com     3
6   111          pikabu.ru     4
7   111  stackoverflow.com     4
8   222             vk.com     1
9   222       facebook.com     2
10  222              vc.ru     3
11  222        twitter.com     4
```

If groups are not divide by `4` get error:

> ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

One possible solution is append values fo0r divide by `4` and last remove them by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
print (df)
    ID           url
0  111        vk.com
1  111      avito.ru
2  111     apple.com
3  111   tiffany.com
4  111     pikabu.ru
5  222        vk.com
6  222  facebook.com
7  222   twitter.com

def f(x):
    a = len(x.index) % 4
    if a != 0:
        x = pd.concat([x, pd.DataFrame(index = np.arange(4-a))])

    x['part'] = np.repeat(np.arange(1, 5), (len(x.index) / 4))
    return x

df = df.groupby('ID').apply(f).dropna(subset=['ID']).reset_index(drop=True)
#if necessary convert to int
df.ID = df.ID.astype(int)
print (df)
    ID           url  part
0  111        vk.com     1
1  111      avito.ru     1
2  111     apple.com     2
3  111   tiffany.com     2
4  111     pikabu.ru     3
5  222        vk.com     1
6  222  facebook.com     2
7  222   twitter.com     3
```

Comment: Why it can return NaN?

Comment: i am not sure, but another solution maybe works better with your real data. Please check it.

Comment: It returns me `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index` in the `df = df.groupby('ID').apply(f)`

Comment: I was afraid about it - problemis some groups are not divide by `4`. But solution is not easy, already working on it.